# How to prevent the background image from getting resized in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, web

I am developing a website.

I have added an oversized background image (bigger than the height and width of the browser to get parallax effect)

The problem i am facing is the moment i resize the browser the image is also getting shrunk.
I don't want to support the resizing of elements on browser size change.
I want to keep everything fixed. Here is the code snippet

```
 $('#background').css({
    "max-width" : "120%",
    "height": "auto",
    "width": "auto\9",
    "background-repeat" : "no-repeat",
    "left":"0px",
"top":"0px",
    "position":"absolute",
    "z-index": "0"
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This [link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) will give you a pretty good idea to play with background images

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: By default, background images don't resize. Stop doing whatever it is that is resizing it.

Comment: You're using a fixed image with percentage-based width/height for your background. Because the height is set to auto, it will stretch as the height gets larger.

Comment: @Quentin I am just new stack overflow so wasn't aware of it. I'll post code from now on instead of links.

Answer (score 2):

try this method

```
body{
  background: url(Resources/BG.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

OR change your inline css for

> img

tag `max-width:100%`

Comment: This works but the image is still getting resized on horizontal resize of the browser. Vertical resize is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Simply remove `max-width: 120%;` from your `<img` tag.

**Method 2**(If you want to do it correctly)

You have following image tag, remove it:

```
<img id="background" src="Resources/BG.png" style="max-width: 120%; height: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
```

Then replace body tag `<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">` with this:

```
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true" style="background:url(Resources/BG.png);">
```

Finaly change the image `BG.png` to some reasonable size like 1024px x 786px, it is too large.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the sample snippet. Just try it in your code:
`<img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-height:100%; max-Width:100%;" src="..">`